# Can anyone tell me whether this is errata or not? "Analysis 1" by Terence Tao

Tags: analysis

[image]

In the Proposition 2.1.16, I guess that

the sentence "Then we can assign a unique natural number a(n) to each natural

number n, such that a(0)=c and a(n++)=f(an) for each natural number n"

should be like this :

"Then we can assign a unique natural number to a(n) for each natural

number n, such that a(0)=c and a(n++)=f(an) for each natural number n"

am i right ??

if I'm wrong and the original text is right, then what is the meaning of it?

please help..

Comment: Well, the original text just means that you have a function
$$\begin{align*} a:\quad\mathbb{N}\quad&\Longrightarrow\quad\mathbb{N}\\ n \quad & \longmapsto \quad a(n) = a_n \end{align*}$$
That just means that every natural number $n$ gets a natural number assigned, that is called $a_n$.

Comment: "assign ... to..." This seems OK to me.  I would not change it to "assign...for...".

Comment: to anyone who downvoted, could you please be nicer to new member?

Comment: thank you very much guys! I should practice English more